# SQL Server storing multiple values in a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Since a variable can only store a single value.This code throws an error.

Objective: If a certain value isnt there in the other table. Add that value in the table plus other columns.

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Code is here as follows:

```
declare @something as varchar(1000)
set @something = (select col1 from d)
while @something not in (select distinct col1 from c)  
begin
   insert into c
   (x,y,z)
   values
   (@something, y, z)
   break
end
```

UPDATE: Found a solution, used an if statement instead.

Comment: Why do you have a `BREAK` in your `WHILE` that isn't conditional? This would only loop once, making the `WHILE` pointless (not that you need a `WHILE` anyway)l.

Comment: SET will accept and assign a scalar (single) value from a query. While SELECT could accept multiple returned values. thats...why yor are getting this error

Comment: Yes I figured that out.

Comment: @@Swarley i also put my answer...you can check out...

Answer (score 2):

Remarks:

1. Your example is incorrect - you do not give information on  y, z
   from where they are inserted
2. you refer to col1 in

   while @something not in (select distinct col1 from c)
   but then refer to this column as x in

> ```
> insert into c    (x,y,z)
> ```

the reason for error is `set @something = (select col1 from d)`
you can still use that one value if it is ok for you by changing the assignment to this

```
set @something = (select top 1 col1 from d)
```

**Solution**
In general, your query is incorrect as you using row-by-row approach instead of set based. Which is a way to go in SQL.

```
insert into c(col1)--,y,z)
select distinct col1 --, y, z 
from d
where not exists (select col1 from c = d.col1)
```

if you have duplicates in **d** for col1 then you need to handle then with **distinct**.
Anyway, the actual result/insert depends on your data and what is in other columns (y,z ...)

Comment: @Swarley . . . The `insert . . . select` is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting Error Just because of SET accept only single value...

**SET will accept and assign a scalar (single) value from a query. While SELECT could accept multiple returned values. thats...why yor are getting this error**

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp1
(Col VARCHAR(100))

insert into #Temp1(col1) select  col1 from c

INSERT INTO c(x,y,z) SELECT Col,y,z FROM #Temp1 WHERE Col <>(select distinct col1 from c) ---Here y,z you can pick from your self...it's not from temp table...

DROP TABLE #Temp1
```

Try this query...

Comment: yup I created a temp table for the workaround.Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a table variable instead:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (
-- specify the desired columns along with the data types
)
```

Then, use your script.

Comment: OP doesn't need a `WHILE` either; demonstrating a simple `INSERT` multi row statement would be great for them.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query ,I hope it will work fine for you.

```
DECLARE @Something TABLE (Col VARCHAR(1000))
INSERT INTO @Something
SELECT col1
FROM d
WHERE Col NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT col1
        FROM c
        )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO c (x,y,z)
    VALUES
    SELECT Col,x,y
    FROM @Something
END
```